# Trouble auto sizing iPhone 5 storyboard to fit iPhone 6

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout, size-classes

I have developed an app using iPhone 5 storyboard. The storyboard contains many views and I haven't used any constraints on any of the views.

What I am trying to achieve is to make the iPhone 5 storyboard expand to fit on iPhone 6 and 6+ without the need for any constraints, is this possible?

I have read many answer on SO already which lead me to believe that it is possible to get it to work but have not yet succeeded.

I don't have any launch images set, and I ticked the 'Use Size Classes' box for the storyboard.

Why is the storyboard not auto sizing for the iPhone 6. It's driving me crazy.

I hope you can help me,

thanks.

Comment: What are you actually seeing when you run on the 6 or 6 plus?

Comment: @jrturton I am seeing the view in the top left hand corner of the simulator, the views are not being stretched out to fill the device screen?

Comment: you can do that in simple way, just add splash screen for 4s and 5 don't add splash for iphone 6 and 6+ , this will make your UI scale

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Use Auto Layout" checkbox shown below

[image]

Also [here is a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) to the size of the Launch images you should be using for the 6 and 6 plus.

Comment: Hi I have tried with both 'Use Auto Layout' and 'Use Size Classes' boxes ticked and I still have the same problem. I haven't added any launch images to the project so should't it work without any launch images?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Autoresizing feature? Uncheck the size classes box and you will see the option to use autoresizing under the measurements section to resize your storyboard for the 6  and 6plus.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM4Vu.png

You wont have to use size constraints since you're only making it for the iPhones

Comment: Hi there, I have unchecked the box and when I go to measurements for the storyboard there is no options, If I got to measurements for the UIView then I can see the auto resizing option, but it is already selected for each view

Comment: Hi again, You have to set the autoresizing options for each individual object in your view, its still much more easier than size restrictions i might add

Answer (score 0):

One way but not recommended. `Don't add splash screen for 6 and 6+`

If you don't add the splash screen for 6 and 6+ OS will automatically scale all your UI.

Comment: I haven't added splash screen at all and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The default auto resizing masks, which you probably have, have a fixed top and left margin and a fixed height and width. This would give you all the views packed into the top left corner as you are seeing - the flexibility is all in the right and bottom margins.

You're seriously better off using constraints (even adding the default constraints will probably get you most of the way there) but if you insist on sticking with auto resizing, you need to set fixed left and right margins and flexible width. Height is a bit more difficult, you have to decide which elements will fill the extra space and have flexible height on those.

To ensure that your app supports multiple screen sizes (instead of just scaling up the smaller interface) you should add a launch image .xib file which is much easier than using lots of images.